# basic complex analysis, confusion about complex exponential and its modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, brownian-motion, eulers-number-e

This question is from the paper 'A new proof of Spitzer's result on the winding of two dimensional Brownian motion' by R Durrett, 1982.

Let $D_t = A_t + iB_t$ be a complex Brownian motion. Then $\int \vert e^{iD_s} \vert ^2 ds = \int e^{2A_s} ds$.

But why? I think by Eulers equation should follow: $\vert e^{iA_s + i^2B_s} \vert ^2 = \vert e^{iA_s}e^{-B_s} \vert ^2= \vert e^{-B_s} \vert ^2 = e^{-2B_s}$

I'd appreciate the help! Thanks :))

Comment: $\vert e^{iA_s + i^2B_s} \vert ^2 = \vert e^{iA_s}e^{-B_s} \vert ^2= \vert e^{-B_s} \vert ^2 = e^{-2B_s}$ is correct. But $\int \vert e^{D_s} \vert ^2 ds = \int e^{2A_s} ds$. I suspect there is a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify the misunderstanding here. Your reasoning is almost correct, but there's a small mistake in the application of Euler's equation. Let's go through it step by step:

Starting from Euler's equation:
$$
\left| e^{i A_s + i B_s} \right|^2 = \left| e^{i A_s} e^{i B_s} \right|^2.
$$

Now, we have:
$$
\left| e^{i A_s} e^{i B_s} \right|^2 = \left| e^{i A_s} \right|^2 \left| e^{i B_s} \right|^2.
$$

Using Euler's equation for each term separately:
$$
\left| e^{i A_s} \right|^2 = \left| \cos(A_s) + i \sin(A_s) \right|^2 = \cos^2(A_s) + \sin^2(A_s) = 1,
$$
and
$$
\left| e^{i B_s} \right|^2 = \left| \cos(B_s) + i \sin(B_s) \right|^2 = \cos^2(B_s) + \sin^2(B_s) = 1.
$$

Hence,
$$
\left| e^{i A_s + i B_s} \right|^2 = \left| e^{i A_s} \right|^2 \left| e^{i B_s} \right|^2 = 1 \cdot 1 = 1.
$$

This means that $\left| e^{i D_s} \right|^2 = 1$, which is not the same as $\left| e^{i D_s} \right|^2 = e^{2 A_s}$.

The correct relation should follow from the fact that $D_t = A_t + iB_t$ is a complex Brownian motion, where both $A_t$ and $B_t$ are real-valued Brownian motions. Then, using the property of the exponential function:
$$
\left| e^{i D_s} \right|^2 = e^{2 \text{Re}(iD_s)} = e^{2 A_s}.
$$

Therefore, $\left| e^{i D_s} \right|^2 = \left| e^{i D_s} \right|^2 = e^{2 A_s}$ as desired.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer does not refer to my question, since $iD_s= iA_s + i^2B_s$ and neither is $Re(iD_s) = A_s$. In fact, $Re(iD_s) = -B_s$.